# Multiple columns is not showing in gridview using web method query in AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I want to show the multiple columns in gridview using web method query in AJAX. When I am doing the query in that more than one field is there while in gridview, it showing the first field data only. I am really confused why it is showing like this because in AJAX gridview I have code for multiple field.

Here is the AJAX method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "schoolregistration.aspx/GetGridData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var customers = xml.find("Table");
        var row = $("[id*=grid_schooldata] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("[id*=grid_schooldata] tr").not($("[id*=grid_schooldata] tr:first-child")).remove();
        $.each(customers, function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("name").text());
            $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("address").text());
            $("[id*=grid_schooldata]").append(row);
            row = $("[id*=grid_schooldata] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        });
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert("error! try again...");
    }
});
```

Here is the web method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string GetGridData()
{
    try
    {
        services frmServices = new services();
        string query = "select name, address from tbl_schoolregistration";
        return frmServices.GetDataSet(query).GetXml();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```